# I'm experiencing an java constructor error

Tags: java, oop, constructor, bluej

I am learning OOP through java. I encountered an error. It occurred at the line `CarV5 car1 = new CarV5(car, endMiles1, startMiles1, gallons1, pricePerGallon1) ;`. It says constructor CarV5 in class CarV5 cannot be applied to given types;

Can you correct my code, so it will run smoothly? 
Can you please send back the full program with your edits?

```
public class CarV5
{

    String carType;
    int endMiles;
    int startMiles;
    double gallonsUsed;
    double pricePerGallon;
    double costOfTrip;
    double milesPerGallon;
    double gallonsPerMile;

    public CarV5(String type, int eMiles, int sMiles, double gals, double PPG, double TotalCost, double MPG, double GPM )
    {
        carType = type;
        endMiles = eMiles;
        startMiles = sMiles;
        gallonsUsed = gals;
        pricePerGallon = PPG;
        costOfTrip = TotalCost;
        milesPerGallon = MPG;
        gallonsPerMile = GPM;
    }

    public int calcDistance(int sMiles, int eMiles)
    {
        return eMiles - sMiles;
    }

    public double calcMPG(int dist, double gals)
    {
        return dist / gals;
    }

    public double calcGPM(double dist, double gals)
    {
        return gals / dist;
    }

    public double totalCost(double pricePerGallon1, double gals)
    {
        return pricePerGallon1 * gals;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int startMiles1 = 70507;
        double distance1, endMiles1;
        double gallons1 = 11.6;
        double MilesperGallon1; 
        double pricePerGallon1 = 2.87;
        double gallonsUsed1,GPM; 
        double totalCost; 
        String car = "07 Ford Focus";

        CarV5 car1 = new CarV5(car, endMiles1, startMiles1, gallons1, pricePerGallon1) ;

        distance1 = car1.calcDistance(startMiles1,endMiles1);
        MilesperGallon1 = car1.calcMPG(distance1,gallons1);
        totalCost = car1.totalCost(pricePerGallon1,gallons1); 

        System.out.printf("%60s\n","Gas Mileage Calculations");
        System.out.printf("%10s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s\n","Type of Car","Start Miles","End Miles","Distance","Gallons","Miles/Gal"); 
        System.out.printf("===================================================================================================\n");
        System.out.printf("%10s%11d%15d%15d%15f%15f\n",startMiles1,endMiles1,distance1,gallons1,MilesperGallon1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve has guidance on trimming this down to the line or two that are giving you problems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor takes 8 parameters, and you're calling it with only 5. You need to either:

1. Add the missing parameters in your call to the constructor.
2. Create an additional constructor that takes only 5 parameters:

   ```
   public CarV5(String type, int eMiles, int sMiles, double gals, double PPG) {
       carType = type;
       endMiles = eMiles;
       startMiles = sMiles;
       gallonsUsed = gals;
       pricePerGallon = PPG;
   }
   ```

   You could even delegate the object creation to your other constructor:

   ```
   public CarV5(String type, int eMiles, int sMiles, double gals, double PPG) {
       super(type, eMiles, sMiles, gals, PPG, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   }
   ```

Also, your declaration of `endMiles1` should be changed to `int` in your main method.

Comment: I'm confused. Why did you take 3 away?

Comment: @aviparshan Like I said, you have two options: either add the 3 missing parameters, or create a constructor that requires only 5 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
double distance1, endMiles1;   
CarV5 car1 = new CarV5(car, endMiles1, startMiles1, gallons1, pricePerGallon1) ;
```

it seems that your endMiles1 is an double while in your constructor it only accepts a double;

```
public CarV5(String type, int eMiles, int sMiles, double gals, double PPG, double TotalCost, double MPG, double GPM )
```

and you have 8 parameters on your constructor why you only have put 5 values on it.

so this completes your constructor requirements.

```
CarV5 car1 = new CarV5(car, endMiles1, startMiles1, gallons1, pricePerGallon1,totalCost,yourMPGVariable,yourGPMVariable) ;
```

and always use camelCase rule on creating a variable . look at your parameter in your constructor, the `TotalCost`  it should be totalCost.